# MailAddress to right Fax server is not working right

Tags: c#, rightfax, mailaddress

I am trying to send email address and right fax service email gateway recive it just like that 
It gives the error here

Tried to remove System.Text.Encoding.ASCII

But still same issue below that is received from right fax

```
TO :- =?us-ascii?Q??/name=3D1000025996-64703714-0/fax=3D0227707689/?
<Right.FAX@x.com>?=" <Right.FAX@x.com>
```

The code & Problem in MailAddress to

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("<Right.FAX@x.com>");

MailAddress to = new MailAddress("<Right.FAX@x.com>", "“/name=" + clientID + "/fax=" + faxNumber + "/” <Right.FAX@x.com>", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
```

Comment: just dont use alphanumeric characters including `<>?/` and etc

Comment: @Simonare right fax receive it in that way 

As MailAddress from works fine 

Received it From :- Right.FAX@x.com

Comment: @Simonare but I will try your solution

Comment: @Simonare thanks your solution worked fine with me, please add this as a solution answer & I will mark it as a best answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just dont use special characters including `<>?/` and etc.